# Erdős–Stone theorem type edge density estimates for bipartite graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The Erdős–Stone theorem theory says that the densest graph not containing a graph H (which has chromatic number r) has number of edges equal to $(r-2)/(r-1) {n \choose 2}$ asymptotically.

However, this doesn't say much for bipartite graphs (since r=2). I wanted to know what are the best results known for the densest graphs not containing a particular bipartite graph H. I'm guessing this problem is still open and hasn't been completely resolved.

This problem is easy if H is a forest, since every graph with $|E| > k|V|$ contains every forest on k vertices as a subgraph. For even cycles, I know there is a result of Bondy and Simonovits which says:

"if $|E| \geq 100k|V|^{1+1/k}$  then G contains a $C_{2l}$ for every $l$ in $[k, n^{1/k}]$."

So can someone point me to the best known results now for bipartite cyclic graphs?

Comment: Do you want birpartite graphs or bipartite cyclic graphs? I would think that bipartite cyclic graphs would be the same as even cycles and the result of Bondy and Simonovits would work.

Comment: Sorry cyclic means containing a cycle as opposed to forests so they are not necessarily cycles. 

Comment: Right. Since forests are easy, the only remaining case is bipartite graphs with cycles. Out of which the cycle graphs are probably covered by the result of Bondy/Simonovits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $ex(n, H)$ denote the maximum number of edges of a graph on $n$ vertices not containing a copy of $H$. The exact bounds are difficult already if you forbid *complete* bipartite graphs $K_{m,n}$.

Erdös, Rényi, Sós (1954) showed that $$ex(n,K_{2,2}) \sim \frac{1}{2}n^{3/2}.$$

According to the classical Kövári-Sós-Turán Theorem (1954), $$ex(n,K_{t,s}) \leq c_{s,t} n^{2-\frac{1}{t}}$$ for $s\geq t\geq 2$,
while a random construction gives the lower bound $$ex(n,K_{t,s})\geq cn^{2-\frac{s+t-2}{st-1}}.$$

Brown (1966) showed Kövári-Sós-Turán is tight for $s=t=3$: $$ex(n,K_{3,3}) \geq cn^{2-\frac{1}{3}},$$ and Füredi (1996) proved that the constant in Brown's construction is optimal, giving $$ex(n,K_{3,3}) \sim \frac{1}{2}n^{2-\frac{1}{3}}.$$

Alon, Kollár, Rónyai, Szabó (1995, 1999) showed that for each $t\geq 2$ there exists $c_t>0$ such that for all $s\geq(t-1)!+1$,
$$ex(n,K_{t,s}) \geq c_tn^{2-\frac{1}{t}},$$ thus matching Kövári-Sós-Turán asymptotically.

I'm not sure if a construction matching Kövári-Sós-Turán has been found for the case $K_{4,4}$. There must also be more known than what is mentioned here. But as you can see, somewhat more than a just a little more is known, although the gaps in our knowledge are still huge here.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Konrad's answer:

No construction is known for $K_{4,4}$. Neither there is a construction for $C_{2k}$ for k other than 2,3,5. There is a construction by [Lazebnik and Woldar](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1284775) that beats the probabilistic for $C_{2k}$, though. There are some non-trivial upper bounds on bipartite graphs of bounded degree and (more generally) of bounded degeneracy. These upper bounds (and some references) can be found in the [survey on dependent random choice](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bsudakov/dependent-random-choice.pdf) by Fox and Sudakov.

Comment: For much more about extremal problems for forbidden bipartite subgraphs, see [this survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5167) by Furedi and Simonovits.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article says that For generalized bipartite graphs H the Erdos-Stone theorem yields ex(n,H) = o(n^2) "and for general bipartite graphs little more is known" see

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Stone_theorem

so as far as I can see you are right that this problem is still open.

Comment: The Wikipedia article doesn't help much. I know that "little more is known." I want to know what little is known today. :-)